# Optimización de expansión de una lista bidimensional, no tengo ni idea

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimización

**Ayuda**, no soy lo suficientemente inteligente para esto.
Puede que no conozca algún método importante y que sea trivial la pregunta pero aun así la voy a hacer.

Mi pregunta:

> Como puedo optimizar el código de aquí abajo, es muy grande y aparatoso para mi gusto.

```
# Creacion de la matriz
m = [[0]]

# Input Usuario para orden de matriz
numeroFilas = int(input("Numero de Filas: "))
numeroColumnas = int(input("Numero de Columnas: "))

# -- Esta es la parte que quiero optimizar --
# Expandimos la matriz
for i in range(numeroFilas-1):
    m.append([0])
for i in range(numeroFilas):
    for j in range(numeroColumnas-1):
        m[i].append(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por completar la respuesta de Candid Moe, un par de aclaraciones.

La sintaxis `[0]*numeroColumnas` produce una lista que contiene `numeroColumnas` ceros. Esto es así, pero entonces cabe preguntarse si, una vez que tenemos esa lista ¿por qué no multiplicarla por `numeroFilas` y obtener la matriz buscada? Es decir ¿se puede hacer lo siguiente?

```
numeroFilas = 3
numeroColumnas = 4
matriz = [[0]*numeroColumnas]*numeroFilas
```

Si lo ejecutamos y miramos `matriz` observamos:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

¡Parece que ha funcionado! Pero hay una **trampa mortal** acechando aquí. Y es que las tres filas de `[0,0,0,0]` *son en realidad la misma*, debido a que la fila se ha creado una vez y luego se ha "multiplicado" `numFilas` veces.

Esto de que las tres sean la misma se observa si por ejemplo intentamos cambiar el segundo número de la segunda fila:

```
matriz[1][1] = 200
```

Si imprimimos ahora la matriz vemos:

```
[[0, 200, 0, 0], [0, 200, 0, 0], [0, 200, 0, 0]]
```

¡Se ha cambiado en las tres filas! Ello se debe a que en realidad, cada uno de los elementos de `matriz` no es sino una referencia a otra lista. En este caso `matriz` contiene tres referencias, pero las tres se refieren a la misma lista. A través de cualquiera de las referencias `matriz[0]`, `matriz[1]` o `matriz[2]` se llega a la misma lista y por ello cambiar un elemento afecta a las tres (porque no hay tres, solo una).

Esto es tremendamente confuso, y se evita con la sintaxis utilizada por CandidMoe:

```
matriz = [[0] * numeroColumnas for x in range(numeroFilas)]
```

Aquí, el bucle `for` (que técnicamente aquí no es un bucle sino una *comprensión de listas*) causa que en cada iteracion se cree una lista diferente, cada una resultado de evaluar `[0]*numeroColumna`. En esta ocasión las tres referencias `matriz[0]`, `matriz[1]` y `matriz[2]` apuntan a tres listas distintas, como debe ser, y no se obtienen extraños efectos secundarios.

Sin embargo cabe preguntarse por qué  `[0]*numFilas` sí que funcionó produciendo una fila con cuatro ceros "diferentes". Porque no son el mismo cero repetido cuatro veces... ¿o sí?

Lo cierto es que **sí**, la lista `[0,0,0,0]` en realidad no contiene cuatro ceros sino cuatro referencias y las cuatro apuntan al mismo cero. Pero cuando cambias uno de esos ceros con algo como `matriz[1][1]=200`, no estás sustituyendo ese 0 por un 200 (si así fuera cambiarían los cuatro elementos de la lista), sino que cambias una de las referencias para que en lugar de apuntar a un 0 apunte a un 200.

Esto es confuso, y por eso quizás sería más claro si se usara la misma sintaxis para crear las filas que la que se usó para crear las columnas, es decir, una *comprensión de listas* en lugar de una multiplicación. La sintaxis que propongo sería entonces:

```
matriz = [[0 for i in range(numeroColumnas)] for i in range(numeroFilas)]
```

El resultado es exactamente el mismo que el de la solución propuesta por CandidMoe, que era perfectamente válida. Es simplemente una sintaxis alternativa que, aunque algo más prolija (y quizás ligeramente más lenta en tiempo de ejecución), es más consistente en mi opinión.

Comment: ¡Increíble explicación, buen trabajo!

Answer (score 2):

Puede ser más corto:

```
# Input Usuario para orden de matriz
numeroFilas = int(input("Numero de Filas: "))
numeroColumnas = int(input("Numero de Columnas: "))
# -- Esta es la parte que quiero optimizar --
# Expandimos la matriz
m = [[0] * numeroColumnas for x in range(numeroFilas)]
```

La expresión

```
[0] * numeroColumnas
```

produce un vector con `numeroColumnas` elementos.

El resto

```
for x in range(numeroFilas)
```

repite lo anterior `numeroFilas` veces.

Como todo está encerrado entre `[]`, produces una lista, en este caso una matriz.

**Demo**

```
>>>Numero de Filas: 3
>>>Numero de Columnas: 4

[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Nota: En tu código tienes invertido filas y columnas.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!